# Why is TaglibSharp unable to read my Id3v2 tag?

Tags: c#, taglib-sharp

I have the following code:

`memoryStream` is a stream that reads an `aac` file from an HLS stream. So it will be a packed AAC with ID3 tags in the beginning.

```
using var tagFile= TagLib.File.Create(new StreamFile(memoryStream), "audio/aac", ReadStyle.Average);
var id3v2tag= (TagLib.Id3v2.Tag)tagFile.GetTag(TagTypes.Id3v2);
var id3v1tag = (TagLib.Id3v1.Tag)tagFile.GetTag(TagTypes.Id3v1);
```

The `tagFile.TagTypesOnDisk` shows that its' of an Id3v2 tag. However, when I inspect `id3v2tag`, there aren't any properties set in there. Instead, it seems that `id3v1tag` is populated instead.

This is causing me issues as I want to be able to read a custom tag we have in there and the only way to do that is if we can use a `TagLib.Id3v2.Tag` type.

Is there something missing?

[image: TagTypesOnDisk]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the `aac` file contains multiple ID3 tags. The first ID3 tag has the private frame of `com.apple.streaming.transportStreamTimestamp`. The second ID3 tag has the rest of the information that I'm looking for, such as title, artist, etc2.

Since there were multiple id3 tags in the aac file, `tagFile.GetTag` did not work. I had to do the following:

```
using var tag = TagLib.File.Create(new StreamFile(memoryStream), "audio/aac", ReadStyle.Average);
// Cast into a combined tag to retrieve the id3v2 variant
var nonContainerTag = (TagLib.CombinedTag)tag.Tag;
var id3v2Tag = (TagLib.Id3v2.Tag)nonContainerTag.Tags.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TagTypes == TagTypes.Id3v2 && x.Title == nonContainerTag.Title);
var customUserTextInformation = id3v2Tag.GetFrames<UserTextInformationFrame>();
```

`customUserTextInformation` would contain the custom ID3 metadata